# Using pairwise identifiers to build an organisational structure

Tags: r

I have a dataset which identifies parent and offspring firms via pairwise combinations. **Some of these parents are also offspring of other parent firms**. I want to build a figurative picture of the structure of an industry in each quarter of my data to find the ultimate owner for each quarter. Why each quarter? Because some subsidiaries are sold or closed the structure changes quarter to quarter complicating these relationships.

The problem I'm having is a very fundamental one. **I need to be able to search for the ultimate owner of a subsidiary in each quarter using an offspring ID.** I have lots of observations and I'm going to have many quarters. This strikes me as computationally intensive.

Please see the below sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  bhr_ownership_start_dt = as.Date(c("1948-10-01", "1952-12-31", "1960-07-01", "1962-08-14", "1951-12-27", "1959-12-31", "1948-10-01")),
  bhr_ownership_end_dt = as.Date(c("1956-05-08", "1956-05-08", "1960-07-07", "1963-04-07", "1966-01-02", "1968-03-06", "1956-01-08")),
  bhr_control_rssd_parent_id = c("1071968", "1071968", "1237894", "910051", "1235957", "1237634", "1052"),
  bhr_control_rssd_offspring_id = c("1256420", "679125", "49764", "1100943", "1230336", "24051", "1071968")
)
```

Below is a shortened version of the desired output (this may not be optimal and open to suggestions) based on the first and last observation in the sample data.

```
df <- data.frame(
  bhr_control_rssd_ultimate_id = c(1052, 1052, 1052, 1052, 1052, 1052, 1052, 1052, 1052, 1052, 1052, 1071968, 1071968, 1071968, 1071968),
  bhr_control_rssd_parent_id = c(1071968, 1071968, 1071968, 1071968, 1071968, 1071968, 1071968, 1071968, 1071968, 1071968, 1071968, 1071968, 1071968, 1071968, 1071968),
  bhr_control_rssd_offspring_id = c(1256420, 1256420, 1256420, 1256420, 1256420, 1256420, 1256420, 1256420, 1256420, 1256420, 1256420, 1256420, 1256420, 1256420, 1256420),
  bhr_quarter_year_dt = c("Q3 1948", "Q4 1948", "Q1 1949", "Q2 1949", "Q3 1949", "Q4 1949", "Q1 1950", "Q2 1950", "Q3 1950", "Q4 1950", "Q1 1951", "Q2 1951", "Q3 1951", "Q4 1951", "Q1 1952") 
)
```

The first observation is a subsidiary of the final observation which is the ultimate parent. I want to identify the ultimate parent firm in each case. There may be many intermediary links between a subsidiary and a parent firm. Note the subsidiary becomes independent from Q2 1951 forward as it was spun off. **The goal is to be able to look up the ultimate firm owner based on offspring or parent ID.**

Comment: So what's the desired output for this sample input? Stack Overflow is specifically designed to provide solutions, not hints. Questions are intended to help future users with the same problem. A question that doesn't provide an answer is not helpful in the long term.

Comment: Please see the updated sample. I apologise for the format, as I'm not sure if the output is efficient for 200+ quarters and 200,000 firm combinations. I suspect there is a much more efficient solution.

Comment: The desired data you provided does not appear to be valid. If I copy/paste I get the error "arguments imply differing number of rows: 15, 14". It doesn't make it easy to see what's different with all these large ID numbers. Are you just trying to populate `bhr_control_rssd_ultimate_id`? Do the date columns matter or are those just noise?

Comment: Corrected, apologies I pasted the raw data into ChatGPT to provide the code to produce the df. Yes, I want to be able to look up the holding company (bhr_control_rssd_ultimate_id) for any company in any quarter as efficiently as possible

Comment: As some of these companies are complex (Russian nesting dolls of shell companies) I'm not sure how to efficiently identify the ultimate holding company as I might need to chain several observations to identify the true holder, having to do this for each period will lengthen processing.

The date columns indicate the period of ownership of the child company by another parent company. I use time and the parent-child relationship to identify the holding company for a particular period. I'm satisfied if I can Identify full quarters of ownership.